# How to overwrite a file on the server when a file is uploaded from a form?

Tags: php, html

Instead of creating a new file, the previously submitted file must be deleted and substituted by the new one.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir .  date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'. $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Move the file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
?>
```

Comment: That depends on how you are persisting the transaction.  Is the user logged in?  and is the context of the upload limited to only that file?  For temporary transactions (sessions), you can store information about the user to indicate the file should be replaced instead of added to a collection.

Comment: Where/how do you track what the "previous submission" is?  You can delete a file as easily as you can save one.  Currently you're saving the file being sent by the user.  Where do you try to delete the "previous" one?

Comment: @David: I do not delete files yet. I just don't know how to implement the needed functionality in the best way. I am using php very rarely. Sorry if the question sounds too easy.

Comment: You need eiher some kind of user tracking or if you dont care about the previous file just delete whatever was in there and upload the new file(always 1 file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need to do two things:

- Track the "previous" file
- Delete the tracked file

Whenever the user uploads a new file, store it as the last file they uploaded.  Session state seems like a reasonable place to track this, at least for now:

```
$_SESSION['lastFile'] = $target_file;
```

Then any time the user uploads another file, also delete whatever the last one was before updating it:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['lastFile'])) {
    // This would be a good place to validate the file path first.
    // Make sure it exists, authorize the user before deleting it, etc.
    unlink($_SESSION['lastFile']);
}
```

If you want to track the "previous file" outside the scope of session state (for example, across re-starts of the web server) then you'd need to track the "previous file" in something like a database record for that user instead.

Comment: Where should I put $_SESSION['lastFile'] = $target_file;

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: Toward the end of the code you already have, I imagine.  It would obviously need to be after the delete and after `$target_file` is defined.  I would probably put it after the file is saved, that way if there's an error in saving the file you won't have clobbered the previous value yet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP upload then write file:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir .  date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'.$_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Move the file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

$file = fopen($target_file,"w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```